# location bar not appearing in InAppBrowser for iOS, Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to load an external page in my iOS app, using Cordova. The page loads fine, but I can't get the location bar to display.

```
    <script>
    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    function onDeviceReady() {
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes', 'toolbar=yes');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop',  function(event) { alert('stop: '  + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
            ref.addEventListener('exit',      function(event) { alert(            event.type); });
        });
    }

</script>

<button id="btn">trigger</button>
```

I can't figure out why the location bar won't load.

I'm appending a navbar and footer to each of my locally stored pages as well, but appending to any container with "data-role=page", and that works well, but obviously it won't work in this instance. I need to find another to do so with external pages.

I'm really only looking for the location bar and buttons so that I can navigate back to my app when the user closes the page.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using Cordova 3.3.0

Comment: Did you resolve this? I encountered the same problem and I tried the suggestions below but it did not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the option parameter in the `window.open` call needs to be a comma-separated string, not strings separated by commas.

This:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes', 'toolbar=yes');
```

should be:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes');
```

As per the [documentation for 3.3.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open):

> The options string must not contain any blank space, and each feature's name/value pairs must be separated by a comma. Feature names are case insensitive. ...

Comment: Wow, talk about a confusing Syntax, huh? Thanks for clarifying this!